# Is the force exerted on a mass, $m$, by a spring equal to $m$ times (acceleration of the mass due to the spring)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, spring

Ignoring friction.

Is the force exerted on a mass, $m$, by a spring equal to $m$ times (acceleration of the mass due to the spring)?

AND

Is the magnitude of the force on a mass due to a spring equal to one value $|F|=kx$? Or does the spring push with less force as it is released (edit: because the $x$ in $kx$ gets smaller)? In other words, do we have to add up the force at each moment the spring is pushing?

[I think I know what the answer is, but I want to confirm it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Yes, provided that no *other* forces act on the mass.

(b) "Is the magnitude of the force on a mass due to a spring equal to one value ||= ? Yes, the magnitude of the force at a particular instant of time is $kx$ in which $x$ is the extension of the spring at that instant.

(c) "Or does the spring push with less force as it is released?" No, not if the 'release' doesn't give time for the extension to change.

(d) "We don't have to add up the force at each moment the spring is pushing?" I can't see why we'd want to do this.